# Time.sleep() is inconsistent and lags on Python 2.7

Tags: python, audio, timer, tkinter

I want to play a tick sound every few seconds in a recursive function with a time sleep in the middle depending on how high the bpm is set in the GUI. This will create a beat. Though the beat is not on rhythm due to lag in the Time.sleep() method. Sometimes it is slow and then it speeds up and is inconsistent.

Is there an alternative I can use to give a consistent pause between beats?

Here is my code:

```
class thalam():
    def __init__(self,root,e):
        self.lag=0.2
        self.root=root
        self.count=0
        self.thread=threading.Thread(target=self.play)
        self.thread.daemon=True
        self.pause=False
        self.e=e
        self.tempo=60.0/120
        self.count=0
    def play(self):
        winsound.PlaySound("tick.wav",winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        time.sleep(self.tempo-self.lag)
        self.count+=1
        if self.count==990:
            self.thread=threading.Thread(target=self.play)
            self.thread.daemon=True
            self.thread.start()
            return
        elif self.pause:
            return
        self.play()
    def stop(self):
        self.pause=True
    def start(self):
        self.pause=False
        self.thread=threading.Thread(target=self.play)
        self.thread.daemon=True
        self.thread.start()
    def settempo(self,a):
        self.tempo=a
class Metronome(Frame):
    def __init__(self,root):
        Frame.__init__(self,root)
        self.first=True
        self.root=root
        self.e=Entry(self)
        self.e.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.e.insert(0,"120")
        self.play=Button(self,text="Play",command=self.tick)
        self.play.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.l=Button(self,text="<",command=lambda:self.inc("l"))
        self.l.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.r=Button(self,text=">",command=lambda:self.inc("r"))
        self.r.grid(row=0,column=2)
    def tick(self):
        if self.first:
            self.beat=thalam(root,self.e)
            self.beat.thread.start()
            self.first=False
        else:
            self.beat.start()
        self.play.configure(text="Stop",command=self.notick)
    def notick(self):
        self.play.configure(text="Start",command=self.tick)
        self.beat.stop()
    def inc(self,a):
        if a=="l":
            try:
                new=str(int(self.e.get())-5)
                self.e.delete(0, END)
                self.e.insert(0,new)
                self.beat.settempo(60.0/(int(self.e.get())))
            except:
                print "Invalid BPM"
                return
        elif a=="r":
            try:
                new=str(int(self.e.get())+5)
                self.e.delete(0, END)
                self.e.insert(0,new)
                self.beat.settempo((60.0/(int(self.e.get()))))
            except:
                print "Invalid BPM"
                return
```

Comment: [*The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the `sleep()` following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep)

Comment: E.g. `time.sleep()` is not an exact time-keeping device. Don't use it as such.

Comment: Why on earth are you using recursion to loop?  You are incurring enormous overhead to replicate what should be done in a `while True:` loop, not to mention that you can very easily overflow the stack.  For example, I could never run your above code in my iPython shell because iPython puts more than 10 frames on the stack.

Comment: Okay well I realized that time.sleep() is inconsistent. Is there an alternative to achieve my goal?

Comment: @MartijnPieters what is then the right approach to use?